# Another function goes ahead of the ther

Tags: php, class

Ok so i have a class and whenever i call out a function or two it skips them why does it happen?

Heres my code:

```
$name = $this->name("Matt"); //returns "Hello Matt";
$welcome = $this->wel();
echo $name."\n";
echo $welcome;
echo "End.";

function name($name){
return "Hello ".$name;
}
function wel(){
return "Good morning";
}
```

But its skipping all the way to ' echo "end"; ' I set a variable and when i tried it again it worked. But its like its skips the lines then goes  back to them
Whats wrong?

Comment: Let me guess: this all is NOT within class definition, right? )

Comment: The functions are defined within the class?  If the lines are being "skipped" that would suggest $name and $welcome are not actually set.  To prove this you could use echo isset($name);

Answer (score 0):

`$this` is only available in functions which are object class members, and called in an object context. "outside", $this will be undefined and NOT an object. Since you're not mentioning any errors/warnings, you've probably got display_errors and error_reporting turned off. You should turn those on, especially when you're testing/developing learning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encase your methods/functions within a class declaration:

`$this` is only available within a class

```
<?php

class yourclass{

    function name($name){
        return "Hello ".$name;
    }

    function wel(){
        return "Good morning";
    }


}

$your_object = new yourclass();

$name = $your_object->name("Matt"); //returns "Hello Matt";

$welcome = $your_object->wel();

echo $name."\n";
echo $welcome;
echo "End.";

?>
```

An example using `$this`

```
<?php
class yourclass{

    function set_name($name){
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    private function welcome(){
        return "Good morning";
    }

    /*example Using $this*/
    function output(){
        echo 'Hello, '.$this->name . PHP_EOL,
              $this->welcome() . PHP_EOL,
             'End.';
    }
}

$your_object = new yourclass();

$your_object->set_name("Matt")->output();
/*
Hello, Matt
Good morning
End.
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is only a snippet of your code, it isn't an implementation of a class. You don't need to use $this to call the functions:

```
$name = name("Matt"); //returns "Hello Matt";
$welcome = wel();
```

Answer (score 0):

When I put all of your code into a class it worked as expected:

```
class Person {
    function __construct() {
        $name = $this->name("Matt"); //returns "Hello Matt";
        $welcome = $this->wel();
        echo $name."\n";
        echo $welcome;
        echo "End.";
    }

    function name($name){
        return "Hello ".$name;
    }
    function wel(){
        return "Good morning";
    }
}


$matt = new Person();
```

Had this output:

```
Hello Matt
Good morningEnd.
```

But I think this might be more of what you're going for:

```
class Person {
    var $name;

    function __construct($name = '') {
        if ($name) $this->name = $name;
    }

    function name(){
        return "Hello " . $this->name;
    }
    function wel(){
        return "Good morning " . $this->name;
    }
}


$person = new Person('Matt');
print $person->name();
print $person->wel();
```

Which had this output:

```
Hello MattGood morning Matt
```